# Furthermore fair dice?

Tags: probability, geometry

In the field of board games, it is immediately apparent that fair die can be constructed for 2, 4, 6, 8, 10, 12 and 20 sides; represented by the coin, tetrahedron, cube, octahedron, decahedron, dodecahedron and icosahedron, respectively.

However, can a fair die be constructed for an arbitrary number of outcomes; say, for instance, a 7-sided die?

Comment: Use a "cylinder" with regular heptagonal cross-section.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dice#Standard_variations) every dice with a number sides of greater 4 and even is a fair dice. 2 and 4 (coin and tetrahedron) are of course fair too. Now we have two options to construct dice with uneven numbered sides:
1. We take an even sided dice with n sides and label number it from $1$ to $n/2$ twice, which, or 
2. We construct a regular k-sided prism and round the edges so we get k sides which all have equal probability for the die to land on.

Answer (score 0):

There is a solution for a fair die for any number $n$ of faces. The obvious answer is a rolling prism with an $n$-sided polygon cross-section. However, if you want to disallow this because of the two extra faces on the top and bottom which actually have a nonzero chance of being selected, you can have an $(n-2)$-sided polygon cross-section.

Assuming a fixed cross-section, you can then adjust the length of the prism for the probabilities of all the faces to be equal: a very flat prism is essentially a coin and has near-$1$ probability of landing on one of the two $(n-2)$-sided faces, whereas a very long one has a near-$0$ chance of this happening. There must therefore be a length for which the probability of landing on each face is equal.

This is very similar to the "3-sided coin" problem which aims at finding the thickness for which a coin has probability 1/3 of landing on its edge (Numberphile has a good video on this). In practice, it seems the answer may depend on the surface on which it's thrown. The only *truly* fair dice which conclusively do not depend on real-world conditions must have only identical faces, and unfortunately not all numbers of faces can produce this (for instance, there is no heptahedron with seven identical faces).